# CentOS / Tomcat / Enabling remote debugging

Tags: tomcat, centos

I'm kinda lost on CentOS. I'm trying to run a Tomcat server in remote debugging mode. But I can't find any catalina.sh, there. The Tomcat server was installed in help of yum. What is the correct way to configure it on CentOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look for `/etc/tomcat5/tomcat5.conf` or `/etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf` or possibly `/usr/share/tomcat6/conf`.  Add your remote debug stuff at the JAVA_OPTS definition

Answer (score 5):

Before you start tomcat execute this command on the shell

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Afterwards you can start tomcat using your start script

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat6 start
```

In eclipse set in remote debug configuration the correct host and port 8000. Check if the port is accessible from outside and is not blocked by firewall.

Answer (score 4):

Modify `/etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf` adding the following row:
`CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"`.
Then start Tomcat with `service tomcat start`.